# WxPython Web Browser Set Title

Tags: python, wxpython

I have created a web browser in python using WxPython. I've been able to get everything to function, go forward/back, reload, ect. My only problem is I'd like to be able to set the title at the top of the program to the title of the web page. I understand how to set the title with `self.SetTitle(title)`, I also know from some of the research I've done that you can get the tile of the page using `self.browser.GetCurrentTitle()`. Only problem with using that is that it's a one time thing that doesn't refresh it's self, when a user clicks a new link. I'm assuming there is some sort of function or something I can catch when a new page is loaded and tell python to do something like this:

```
def OnLoad(self, event):
     self.webtitle = self.browser.GetCurrentTitle()
     self.browser.SetTitle(self.webtitle)
```

Or something along those lines I'm just not sure where or how I can connect or "catch" that function. I have read through the documentation of `wx.html2.WebView`, but I'm not able to make sense of how to do this, I have also looked through this site as well as a few mailing lists but I can't seem to find anything that would explain how to do this.

Here is the main code that will run my browser (obviously I've shortened it).

```
class PyBrowser(wx.Frame): 
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwds): 
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
    self.SetTitle('PyBrowser')
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseWindow)
    #Element Variables 
    self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self) 
    self.address = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="http://",size=(500, 26))
    self.go = wx.Button(self, label="Go", id=wx.ID_OK)
    self.back = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('img/Back Button.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG), size=(26,26) ,style=wx.NO_BORDER)#wx.Button(self, label="Back") 
    self.forward = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('img/Forward Button.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG), size=(26,26) ,style=wx.NO_BORDER)#wx.Button(self, label="Forward")
    self.reload = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('img/Reload Button.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG), size=(26,26) ,style=wx.NO_BORDER)#wx.Button(self, label = "Refresh")
    self.result = None
    #Nav area
    addressarea = wx.BoxSizer()
    addressarea.Add(self.address, proportion = 1, border = 0)
    ...
    #Adding elements
    sizer.Add(addressarea, proportion = 0, flag = wx.EXPAND, border = 0)
    sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10) 
    #Button binding
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnGo, id=wx.ID_OK)
    ...
    #Menu bar stuff
    #File Menu
    self.fileMenu = wx.Menu()
    self.New = self.fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'New Window')
    ...
    #Help Menu
    self.helpMenu = wx.Menu()
    self.Help = self.helpMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Help')
    ...
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.OnHelp,self.Help)
    ...
    #Adding the actual Menu Bar

    self.menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
    self.menuBar.Append(self.fileMenu, 'File')
    self.menuBar.Append(self.helpMenu, 'Help')
    self.SetMenuBar(self.menuBar)

    self.SetSizer(sizer) 
    self.SetSize((1000, 700)) 
  def OnGo(self, event):
    self.result = self.address.GetValue()
    self.browser.LoadURL(self.result)
 if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = wx.App() 
    dialog = PyBrowser(None, -1) 
    dialog.browser.LoadURL("http://www.google.com") 
    dialog.Show() 
    app.MainLoop()
```

To summarize what I'm asking is how to I set the title of a wx.Frame to the current title of a web page inside of wx.html2.WebView and change the name every time a new link is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

The webview events that you require are listed [here](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html2.WebView.html?highlight=webview#events-events-emitted-by-this-class)

Comment: Took me a minute, but I found what you were talking about. Not a complete answer, but it does answer a little. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would catch the `EVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED` event and update the title in the event handler. I believe you could do something like this:

```
def onLoaded(self, event):
    title = self.browser.GetCurrentTitle()
    self.SetTitle(title)
```

What may be even better is to catch `EVT_WEBVIEW_TITLE_CHANGED` as that actually detects when the page title changes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that from what Mike said, using an event to catch it would work. So instead of `EVT_WEBVIEW_TITLE_CHANGED` I used `EVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED`, I then binded the event to my function to handle changing the title. It looked like this:

```
#Binding the function the event to the function. 
self.Bind(wx.html2.EVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED, self.OnPageLoad, self.browser)

#Function binding to the page loading 
def OnPageLoad(self, event):
    self.WebTitle = self.browser.GetCurrentTitle()
    self.SetTitle(self.WebTitle)
```